# how can I arrange button and work on all device in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

how can I arrange button and work on all device like the picture below?

The yellow color is a button and other colors just design.

I try **RelativeLayout** but doesn't work the same arrangement in another device 
and try **LinearLayout** but doesn't come in the same arrangement.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button34"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/out_up" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button33"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/green" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button36"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button37"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button38"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button39"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button40"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button35"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/green_down" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button43"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_out_up" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button44"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button42"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button45"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button47"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button46"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button41"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_out_down" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button49"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/out_up_right" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button53"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/right_red" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button54"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/right_red" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button55"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/right_red" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button56"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/right_red" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button57"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/right_red" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button52"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/right_red" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button48"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/out_down_right" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button51" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in Android Studio the result like this:

[image]

Comment: All android layouts are rectangular, so how are you building this layout? Using drawables?

Comment: by using image button or button and background and every shape i make it by Photoshop . is work but not with the same arrangement

Comment: Can you share your XML layout with an [edit]?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want distortion in you layout you need to define a "safe area" or "board area" which is a fixed aspect ratio.

You then need to pad this "safe area" with a floating pad on the width and / or the height.

For example:

```
------------------------------------------
| pad =============================== pad |
| + + ======     safe area     ====== + + |
| pad =============================== pad |
| + + ======     safe area     ====== + + |
| pad =============================== pad |
| + + ======     safe area     ====== + + |
| pad =============================== pad |
| + + ======     safe area     ====== + + |
| pad =============================== pad |
------------------------------------------
```

Or for a screen that is not as wide

```
-----------------------------------
| + pad + + pad + + pad + + pad + |
| =============================== |
| ======     safe area     ====== |
| =============================== |
| ======     safe area     ====== |
| =============================== |
| ======     safe area     ====== |
| =============================== |
| ======     safe area     ====== |
| =============================== |
| + pad + + pad + + pad + + pad + |
-----------------------------------
```

In both examples the "safe area" is the same size and only the padding has changed.

Comment: what you mean of safe area

Comment: "safe area" is the section of the screen that you want to have on all screens sizes without distortion. This is the section of the screen that will always been seen no matter what the screen width and height are.